# Как удалить переменную после использования в Python?

Tags: python, переменные

**Делаю бота на Python**
*он должен выдать рандомные данные из переменной и удалить, ( чтобы избежать повторений)*
Как удалить переменную вместе с данными?

Comment: как связано удаление переменной и исключение повторений?

Comment: Долгая история)

Answer (score 5):

`del name`

`del name[i]`

`del name[i:j:k]`

`del name.attribute`

В первой форме `name` — это имя переменной, взятое буквально. В последних трех формах `name` может являться выражением.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ)